# Draw a rectangle in JavaScript with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am a JavaScript beginner, an want to make my first website.

I have a rectangle, and i would like to draw another one inside of this rectangle with the mouse.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.rect(0, 20, canvas.width, 50);
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fill();

var canvasOffset;
var offsetX;

var startX

canvasOffset = $("#myCanvas").offset();
offsetX = canvasOffset.left;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  canvas.style.cursor = "ew-resize";

  startX = parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX);
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "X position: " + startX;
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  canvas.style.cursor = "default";

  var mouseX = parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX);

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(startX, 20, mouseX - startX, 50);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();

  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "X old: " + startX + " - X new :" + (mouseX) + " - Length: " + (mouseX - startX);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

canvas {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1></h1>
</header>
<section>
  <canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <p id="info"></p>
</section>
<footer>David Kester</footer>
```

If you try on the blue rectangle you will understand what i want. The problem is that the new rectangle won't be draw from were we click to where we release the mouse. it has an offset.

I do not know what is wrong, it might be something about the offset and coordinates. But i already tried something other people implementations but it does not work with me.

Could it be that i am messing with pixels and non pixels? in the CSS i have pixels.

Comment: try using an open source library to ease you way into javascript, like KineticJS

Comment: here is a clue: http://jsfiddle.net/1mca6xqq/1/ when you click, it starts to draw, i think your offset is off

Comment: its probably because you are using the width as a percentage...this will slightly offset the drawings in the canvas

Comment: I am using percentage because a would like te site to work in every screen. Is this a good manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is you are only setting the size of the canvas using css which causes stretching issues. This is alright to do so long as you factor in the stretch factor (scaling). You also need to consider that the offset of the canvas changes if you resize the window after it has been loaded so you need to start your events off with the following code.

```
var scale = canvas.attr("width") / canvas.width(),
    offsetX = $("#myCanvas").offset().left;
```

Also you need to set the canvas width and height attribute for this to function properly. You can set the width to anything but the higher the number the better the detail.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="90">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Another tip is to use jQuery functions more for event handling, element selection, and attribute setting.

```
var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
...
canvas.mouseup(function () {
    ...
    canvas.attr("cursor", "ew-resize");
    ...
});
...
canvas.mousedown(function () {
    ...
});
```

Here's a functioning code snippet:

```js
var canvas = $("#myCanvas"),
  context = canvas[0].getContext("2d"),
  startX;

context.rect(0, 20, canvas[0].width, 50);
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fill();

canvas.mousedown(function() {
  var scale = canvas.attr("width") / canvas.width(),
    offsetX = $("#myCanvas").offset().left;

  canvas.attr("cursor", "ew-resize");

  startX = parseInt((event.clientX - offsetX) * scale);
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "X position: " + startX;
});

canvas.mouseup(function() {
  var scale = canvas.attr("width") / canvas.width(),
    offsetX = $("#myCanvas").offset().left;

  canvas.attr("cursor", "default");

  var mouseX = parseInt((event.clientX - offsetX) * scale);

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(startX, 20, mouseX - startX, 50);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();

  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "X old: " + startX + " - X new :" + (mouseX) + " - Length: " + (mouseX - startX);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}

header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

canvas {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <h1></h1>

</header>
<section>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="90">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <p id="info"></p>
</section>
<footer>David Kester</footer>
```

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/1mca6xqq/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the functioning fiddle. I was not aware that the attributes of the canvas differs from the ones in CSS. I have a last question, the idea is to have zeven of this bars, and after the new rectangles are draw, i would get their position and do some operations with it. Should i make a new canvas for each bar, or would you suggest making all the bar's in the same canvas?

Comment: i would try to use one canvas for this situation...but then again i am not sure what your requirements are...imo there is a always an easy way and a right way (sometimes they are the same) but looks like multiple canvas's here would be the easy way while one canvas would be the right way.